# Angular 1.6 Upgrade causes: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ngtable, angularjs-1.6

Upgraded to Angular 1.62 and a working set of complex arrays stopped working and I get this error early in page load.  I think I am loosing track of the $index?

```
$scope.purchaseList = vm.pq.purchaseItemsList;
                            vm.tabledataNew = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.purchaseList.length; i++) {
                                vm.tabledataNew[i] = {};
                                var datat = $scope.purchaseList[i];
                                vm.tabledataNew[i].tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                                    total: datat.mainProductAndAddons.length
                                }, {
                                    dataset: datat.mainProductAndAddons
                                });
                            }

<div class="st-table pq-items" ng-repeat="itemgroup in purchaseList track by $index" ng-show="ctrl.showNoItems == false">
                <table class="table" ng-table="ctrl.tabledataNew[$index].tableParams">
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
                        <td data-title="'Item'"sortable="'description'" class="first">{{::item.description}}</td>
                        <td data-title="'List Price'" sortable="'listPrice'">{{::item.listPrice | currency}}</td>
                        <td data-title="'Discount'" sortable="'discountAmount'">{{::item.discountAmount | currency}}</td>
                        <td data-title="'Final Price'" sortable="'finalPrice'">{{::item.finalPrice | currency}}</td>
                        <td class="last"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Nothing suspicious going on here (I think). Try loading your project with `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and you'll be able to see much detailed error messages.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  We did find it to not be in the code, but a very odd table format block that caused us to loose the index.